# How to put special characters in Corona SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, coronasdk

I don't know how to make this work.

```
local myText = display.newText( "Święta", 100, 200, native.systemFont, 16 )
```

It shows question marks for first and fourth letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean smulator or real device? It works fine on my laptop. I use Corona SDK v.2016.2992 and polish version of Win7 64bit.

Try save lua files with encoding set up as UTF-8 without BOM. In [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) find "Encoding->Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". I'm using [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) ("File->Save with Encoding->UTF-8").

More information you may find in [Problem displaying international (Norwegian) characters](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/46927-problem-displaying-international-norwegian-characters/).